# Golang Read Bytes from net.TCPConn

Tags: tcp, go

Is there a version of `ioutil.ReadAll` that will read until it reaches an EOF OR if it reads `n` bytes (whichever comes first)?

I cannot just take the first `n` bytes from an `ioutil.ReadAll` dump for DOS reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[io.ReadFull](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull)
or
[io.LimitedReader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#LimitedReader)
or
[http.MaxBytesReader](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#MaxBytesReader).

If you need something different first look at how those are implemented, it'd be trivial to roll your own with tweaked behavior.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to achieve your requirement. You can use either one.

[func ReadFull](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull)

```
func ReadFull(r Reader, buf []byte) (n int, err error)
```

> ReadFull reads exactly len(buf) bytes from r into buf. It returns the
>   number of bytes copied and an error if fewer bytes were read. The
>   error is EOF only if no bytes were read.

[func LimitReader](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#LimitReader)

```
func LimitReader(r Reader, n int64) Reader
```

LimitReader returns a Reader that reads from r but stops with EOF after n bytes. The underlying implementation is a *LimitedReader.

[func CopyN](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#CopyN)

```
func CopyN(dst Writer, src Reader, n int64) (written int64, err error)
```

> CopyN copies n bytes (or until an error) from src to dst. It returns
>   the number of bytes copied and the earliest error encountered while
>   copying. On return, written == n if and only if err == nil.

[func ReadAtLeast](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadAtLeast)

```
func ReadAtLeast(r Reader, buf []byte, min int) (n int, err error)
```

> ReadAtLeast reads from r into buf until it has read at least min
>   bytes. It returns the number of bytes copied and an error if fewer
>   bytes were read. The error is EOF only if no bytes were read.

Comment: Worth noting that ReadFull uses ReadAtLeast underlyingly.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options. If `n` is the number of bytes you want to read and `r` is the connection.

Option 1:

```
p := make([]byte, n)
_, err := io.ReadFull(r, p)
```

Option 2:

```
p, err := io.ReadAll(&io.LimitedReader{R: r, N: n})
```

The first option is more efficient if the application typically fills the buffer.

If you are reading from an HTTP request body, then use [http.MaxBytesReader](http://godoc.org/net/http#MaxBytesReader).